# How to select size for display in Firefox's Responsive Design View using Shortcuts?

Tags: firefox, responsive-design, cross-browser, browser-testing

Reading [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_View) I understand it is possible to invoke Responsive Design View with `⌥⌘M`.

I want to be able to select different view sizes from the dropdown without using a mouse.

Are there shortcuts available for selecting these different view sizes after Responsive Design View is invoked?

Comment: I can't find a way to do this, either.  However, I'm working around it by opening several different tabs with the same document loaded, but setting different sizes/orientations on each tab.  As I develop, I can refresh all the tabs and step through them without touching the mouse.